# Angular.js $scope and controller again

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I know there are many questions regarding the angular $scope by after a couple of hours I still can't figure out what is wrong. I'm using Angular.js with Ionic but the problem should be angular related.

In my App I need a "add to wishlist" function. In the productDetail view when someone tapps "add to wishlist" I add this product with a service and webSQL to the database. Now when the user goes to the wishlist view I get all saves products but the view doesn't update.

I have a file menu.html with an Ionic side-menu:

```
  <ion-side-menu side="left" expose-aside-when="large" width="72">
        <ion-content>
          <ion-list ng-controller="LeftMenuCtrl">
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close ng-href="#/app/wish" ng-click="updateWishList()" ng-class="{'current': isActive('/app/wish')}">
          <span class="icon icon-menu-wish"></span>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
```

The "LeftMenuCtrl" handels the hover for the active menu item.
In my WishListView I would like to show the current added products:
File wishList.html

```
<ion-view hide-nav-bar="true" view-title="WISHLIST" ng-controller="WishlistCtrl">
  <div class="bar bar-header bar-stable">
    <div class="header-wrapper">
      <!--heading-->
      <div class="dash-slider-wrapper"" >
        <div class="header-text-main">WHISH</div> <div class="header-text-sub">LIST</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ion-content class="has-header">
    <ion-item class="product-card" ng-repeat="product in products">
      <div class="card">
        EAN: {{product.ean}}
      </div>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

And the controller:

```
app.controller("WishlistCtrl", function($scope, $state, productService) {

//gets called when the controller is loaded

    productService.getWishlistProducts().then(function (products) {
      $scope.products = products;
    });

//gets called when the user clicks on the navi but does not 
//update the $scope (or it updates the wrong $scope)

    $scope.updateWishList = function () {
      productService.getWishlistProducts().then(function (products) {
        $scope.products = products;
      });
    };
  })
```

Can anyone tell me whats wrong here please?

**Edit:**
This is the state for the menu link:

```
  .state('app.wish', {
    url: "/wish",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/wish.html"
      }
    }
  })
```

**Edit2:**
When I refresh the page, I see all added products. But not immediately. It's like the

```
$scope.updateWishList = function () ...
```

creates another $scope...

**Edit3:**

```
app.controller('ProductDetailCtrl', function($stateParams ,$state, $scope, productService, $ionicHistory, $ionicPopup) {
    $scope.addToWishlist = function(ean) {

      productService.addProductToWishlist(ean).then(function(response) {
        if(response == "OK") {
          var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'product added to wishlist',
            template: 'You can go to your wishlist to see all your marked products'
          });
        }
      });
    };
})
```

**Edit4:** 
I added a Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/0woPfN
It´s not working but you can see the code there (I deleted unnecessary stuff)

Comment: Looks like it directs you to a different state, no?

Comment: Yes, I will edit the code above...

Comment: So if clicking the item changes states and in the new state you have `WishlistCtrl` that calls `productService.getWishlistProducts()`, why do you need to update? The updating doesn't matter as you're changing states, the scope is destroyed and a new one is created for the controller of the new HTML.

Comment: In my product detail page I add a new product to my wishlist (via a service and webSQL). But my wishlist view doesn't know that there is a new product in the list. So I try to update the list everytime the user goes to that wishlist (or goes the #/wish state)....

Comment: Yes I understand, but not sure why you're writing it like that. The WishList view should fetch from the server when it loads, and it appears to be doing that inside WishlistCtrl, how does that not work ?

Comment: Anyway, what I was referring to earlier is this: `ng-href="#/app/wish" ng-click="updateWishList()"` You're having a function execute on click, but it doesn't matter since you're switching states, and the old controller scope is destroyed.

Comment: I will try to create a fiddle to show you the problem...

Comment: That would be great.

Comment: I created a plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/0woPfN unfortunately its not working properly (could figure out why) but you see the full code here (I stripped away the unnecessary code and the webSql stuff). The important part is located in the WishlistCtrl and ProductDetailCtrl

Comment: I see a blank page.. am I missing something?

Comment: As I said... it`s not working (couldn't figure out why). But you can have a look at the sourcecode. The problem is still that the update function in the menu (sidebar) doesn't update the wishlist view (wish.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have 2 declaration of the `WishlistCtrl`.

Once in the app.js:

```
.state('app.wish', {
    url: "/wish",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "wish.html",
        controller: 'WishlistCtrl' //here is the first declaration
      }
    }
  })
```

Second in the HTML:

```
<ion-view hide-nav-bar="true" view-title="WISHLIST" ng-controller="WishlistCtrl">
```

Remove either one and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got it working.
First in the StateProvicer I added a resolve method:

```
  .state('app.wish', {
    url: "/wish",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/wish.html",
        controller: 'WishlistCtrl',
        resolve: {
          products: function(productService) {
            return productService.getWishlistProducts()
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

And to update the model when a new product gets added to the wishlist:

```
  .controller("WishlistCtrl", function($scope, $state, productService, products) {

    //set wishlist products on controller load
    $scope.products = products;

    //updated wishlist when a new product gets added
    $rootScope.$on('updatedWishList', function() {
      console.log('List has been updated. ');
      productService.getWishlistProducts().then(function (products) {
        $scope.products = products;
      });
    });
  })
```

Easy... when you know how :D